# difference between systems approach and systemic approach

Tags: phrase-meaning

there seem to be very distinct meanings between systems and systemic approaches. However, the Latter, which i came across lately, means considering all attributes of an entire system in order to achieve desired results, as google says. And the former, which i translated many times before, conveys almost similar meaning-emphasize the context, not components individually, to achieve desired results. So, my assumption about these two being wide apart poles, is absurd. Right?

1. Systemic approaches emphasize the importance of context in determining the way we live our lives and the practice of........
2. By applying a systems approach we are better able to align individual and organizational goals with strategic directions and stakeholder needs.

Comment: These are jargon terms and don't necessarily mean what the individual words mean.

Answer (score 0):

A quick googling has a few varying definitions for Systems Approach:

> **Systems Approach**
>
> 1. The approach stands on the assumption that breaking down of a complex concept into simple easy to understand units helps in better understanding of the complexity. [Reference](https://www.phe.gov/Preparedness/planning/mscc/healthcarecoalition/chapter1/Pages/systemsbasedapproach.aspx).
> 2. A systems-based approach to emergency response means that the disparate elements that are required to perform response operations are viewed as interrelated components of a single system. [Reference](https://www.phe.gov/Preparedness/planning/mscc/healthcarecoalition/chapter1/Pages/systemsbasedapproach.aspx).
>
> I'd pick the latter: the system should be viewed in it's entirety and not just as the combination of it's sub-parts.

As for the Systemic Approach:

> **Systemic Approach**
>
> > means considering all attributes of an entire system in order to
> >     achieve desired results
>
> I agree to the definition you provided.

Comment: So there is no difference in meanings of these two phrases, isnt it?

Comment: My feeling is that while both tend to mean the same, the 'systems approach' is more of a technical word used in formal literature, example: a specific field of study. While 'systemic approach' can be used more commonly. But as you said, they don't seem to differ too much and depending on the context one can be used in place of the other.

Comment: thank you very much :)

Comment: They're both jargon, and mean different things to different "experts".  "Systems approach" is probably about 10 years older and a lot more common, according to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=systems+approach%2C+systemic+approach&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csystems%20approach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csystemic%20approach%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csystems%20approach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csystemic%20approach%3B%2Cc0).